# Commutators in the reduced C*-algebra of the free group

Tags: reference-request, oa.operator-algebras, c-star-algebras

Is it known whether any element of trace 0 in the reduced $C^*$-algebra of a non-abelian free group, is a limit of sums of (additive) commutators?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

This is true.  Perhaps it is known whether this property for a group $G$ is equivalent to $C^*_\lambda G$ having a unique trace?  In any case, the same proof of Powers which shows unique trace for free groups, can be adapted to this question.

First note that if $F = F(x_1, x_2, \ldots, x_n)$ is the free group on $n$ generators, then by a trick of Bob Powers, in $\mathcal B(\ell^2 F)$ we have $\| \Sigma_{i = 1}^n \lambda(x_i) \| \leq 2 \sqrt{n}$.  Indeed, if we denote by $P_i$ the projection in $\mathcal B(\ell^2 F)$ onto the subspace generated by Dirac functions on all words which in reduced form begin with the letter $x_i$, then we have $(1 - P_i) \lambda(x_i) (1 - P_i) = 0$ and hence 
$$
\Sigma_{i = 1}^n \lambda(x_i) = \Sigma_{i = 1}^n P_i \lambda(x_i) + ( \Sigma_{i = 1}^n P_i \lambda(x_i) (1 - P_i))^*.
$$
Since $P_i$ have orthogonal ranges we have that $\| \Sigma_{i = 1}^n P_i \lambda(x_i) \| \leq \sqrt{n}$ and $\| \Sigma_{i = 1}^n P_i \lambda(x_i) (1 - P_i) \| \leq \sqrt{n}$.

Next note that the limits of sums of commutators forms a subspace and hence it is enough in the reduced group $C^*$-algebra to show that the non-trivial group elements can be written as a limit of a sums of commutators.  Moreover, in a free non-abelian group, every element has an element which is free from it, and hence by restricting to a subgroup it is enough to show that in the free group on 2 generators $F(a, b)$ we can write $\lambda(a)$ as a limit of sums of commutators.

For this we consider an arbitrary $n \in \mathbb N$ and easily verify the formula
$$
\frac{1}{n} \Sigma_{i = 0}^{n -1} \lambda( b^{-i} a b^i )
= \lambda(a) - \frac{1}{n}\Sigma_{i = 1}^{n - 1} [ \lambda(b^i), \lambda(b^{-i} a) ].
$$

Since $x_i \mapsto b^{-(i - 1)} a b^{(i - 1)}$ extends to an isomorphism between $F(x_1, \ldots, x_n)$ to the subgroup $\langle a, b^{-1} a b, \ldots, b^{-(n - 1)}a b^{(n - 1)} \rangle$ it follows from Powers trick that 
$$
\| \lambda(a) - \frac{1}{n}\Sigma_{i = 1}^{n - 1} [ \lambda(b^i), \lambda(b^{-i} a) ] \| \leq 2/ \sqrt{n}.
$$
Since $n$ was arbitrary, this finishes the proof.

Comment: Very impressing!   

Comment: You are right with your suggestion. Let $C$ be the norm closure of the span of additive commutators, then any linear functional on $(C^{\ast}_{\lambda}G)/C$ defines a trace on $C^{\ast}_{\lambda}G$. Hence, if there is a unique trace, then $C \subset C^{\ast}_{\lambda}G$ has codimension one. Clearly, $C$ has to coincide with the space of those elements with vanishing trace.

Comment: This will give a linear functional with the tracial property, but it's not quite clear to me why it would give a state.  I may be missing something.

Comment: No, it will not be unital or positive in general. I thought "uniqueness of trace" means uniqueness of continuous linear functionals with the tracial property.

Comment: I always interpreted that as unique tracial state, but perhaps these two uniqueness conditions are equivalent on reduced group $C^*$-algebras.

Comment: Off the top of my head, isn't there a Hahn-Jordan decomposition for traces? (The real and imaginary parts of a trace are clearly tracial; then if you write a self-adjoint trace as the difference of two positive functionals via Jordan decomposition, and consider conjugating each of these functionals by the same fixed unitary, uniqueness of the decomposition tells you that both functionals are tracial -- I think this argument is in a paper of Bunce and Paschke.) So if there is a unique tracial state then I think this implies that the space of traces is one-dimensional

Comment: @JessePeterson  Is there an example of a non simple $C^{*}$ algebra $A$ which is unital with trivial center and posses a faithful trace with the property under the main question of this post?

Comment: @YemonChoi Something related to it is proven in "Equivalence and traces on C*-algebras" by Cuntz and Pedersen (Proposition 2.7 and 6.7). Indeed, the real linear span of the tracial state space is isometrically isomorphic to the real Banach space of self-adjoint bounded linear functionals which are tracial, which again is isomorphic to $A_q^*$.

Answer (score 10):

More is true: an element of a C*-algebra is a norm limit of sums of commutators if and only if it is 0 on any bounded trace. For selfadjoints, this was proven by Cuntz and Pedersen (in their only paper together I think). One reduces from arbitrary elements to selfadjoints by writing $c=a+bi$, with $a$ and $b$ selfadjoint. So if $C^*_r(G)$ has a unique tracial state then any element vanishing on it is a limit of sums of commutators.

A couple more  facts proven by Cuntz and Pedersen: (1) the commutators can be arranged to form a convergent series, (2) for selfadjoints, the commutators can be chosen of the form $x^* x-x x^*$.

Comment: The paper is: Cuntz, Joachim; Pedersen, Gert Kjaergȧrd
"Equivalence and traces on $C^{\ast} $C∗-algebras."
J. Funct. Anal. 33 (1979), no. 2, 135–164. (They wrote 2 papers together!)  See http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=546503